# Organize files with batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I need to somehow copy all files from source folder(including subfolders) to destination folder keeping the subfolders name as a file name.

Using batch file on windows.

Example:

```
sourceFolder\packed1.bin
sourceFolder\data1\packed1.bin
sourceFolder\data1\packed2.bin
sourceFolder\data1\zz\packed1.bin
sourceFolder\data1\aa\packed1.bin
sourceFolder\data1\aa\22\packed1.bin
```

should become...

```
destinationFolder\packed1.bin
destinationFolder\data1-packed1.bin
destinationFolder\data1-packed2.bin
destinationFolder\data1-zz-packed1.bin
destinationFolder\data1-aa-packed1.bin
destinationFolder\data1-aa-22-packed1.bin
```

I tried using `goto` but I cannot keep the track of which directory I am in and then return to it.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set mypath=%cd%
set "_orig=%mypath%\datafolder"
set "_origCurr=%_orig%"
set "_dest=%mypath%\untree\"

set procDirs
set /a procDirsL=0
set currDirS=""
set /a isProc=0

:gofolders
for /d %%D in ("%_dest%\*.*") do (
set currDirS=%currDirS%\%%D
set procDirs[!procDirsL!]

set /a procDirsL=!procDirsL!+1


goto gofolders
)

:dofiles
for /f %%F in ("%_dest%\*.*") do (

)
goto gofolders
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I did a similar thing using python and just a character replacement with the os library

Comment: What did you try till now?  We will gladly help you with the issue if some effort is shown.

Comment: @DDS Hi thanks, I need in batch file for windows I need to run batch file from different places

Comment: @tukan I added something that is left, thanks

Comment: Type `xcopy /?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Set target and destination paths.
set "target=%cd%\sourceFolder"
set "dest=%cd%\destinationFolder"

rem Make dest dir if needed.
if not exist "%dest%" md "%dest%"

rem Recurse target and get filepath of .bin files.
for /r "%target%" %%A in (*.bin) do call :moveToDest %%A
exit /b

:moveToDest
setlocal
set "oldname=%~1"

rem Remove target from the filepath.
call set "newname=%%oldname:%target%=%%"
if not defined newname (
    >&2 echo target is undefined
    exit /b 1
)

rem Remove leading \.
if "%newname:~,1%" == "\" set "newname=%newname:~1%"

rem Replace \ with -.
set "newname=%newname:\=-%"

rem Copy new named file to dest.
copy "%oldname%" "%dest%\%newname%" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    >&2 echo Failed to copy "%oldname%" to "%dest%\%newname%"
    exit /b 1
)
exit /b
```

Set `target` and `dest` before executing.

As the destination files are renamed and copied to
destination with no subfolder structure, making the
destination folder is done at the start only once.

The target folder is recursed with the `for` loop
and gets all the fullpaths to the `.bin` files.
The label `:moveToDest` is called with argument
of the fullpath to each `.bin` file.

In the label `:moveToDest`, the argument passed
is set to `oldname`. The target path is removed
and leading backslash if needed. This sets oldname
as a relative path from the target path.
The backslashs are replaced with dashes to create
the filename for copy. Copies the `.bin` file
using `copy` to copy from the target to the
destination with the new filename.

Comment: So I was close to it with this goto to process files. You would know to do same thing with vbscript it is possibly?

Comment: VBScript I expect could do this task. Many languages would have the ability.